# Using age categories in regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I used multiple age categories (under18, 18-35, 36-44 etc.) in my survey. So I recoded each interval as a dummy variable. I know it's not 100% correct to use something like age as categorical variables. Is there actually any literature which argues for this method and which legitimates the way I did this.

Best
Kevin

---

This was just me writing example to point out my issue. I actually binned it differently. How would you justify it? Do you have any literature to underpin this?

Comment: Do not need literature, just common sense. Think about 3 persons with age 18, 35, 36. 18 and 35 are the same, 35 and 36 are different, Is it good/reasonable?

Comment: I think binning ages can be justifiable, but this seems like a very strange way to bin ages.  I would argue a 22 year old is much different than a 32 year old in most ever respect.  The risk you run when binning is that you characterize the effect of age by having bins be too wide.

Comment: Hey Demetri, this was just me writing example to point out my issue. I actually binned it differently. How would you justify it? Do you have any literature to underpin this?

Comment: This is very common in real research. You just aren't going to get people to respond with their real age. You'll either have missing data, or complete nonresponse. No one even tries to get real ages. In biomedical research, age at a finer resolution than years is considered PHI, & note that age in years is already binned / interval censored, just at a finer grain size.

Comment: So using age as categorical variables is totally fine just to enable an easy experience for the candidates?

Answer (score 5):

It's true that categorizing continuous variables can lead to some problems, but it can also help approximate a complex model more easily. For the same number of degrees of freedom, though, it might be preferable to fit a flexible linear model (e.g., a spline or polynomial model). That said, there is some (older) literature that justifies splitting into categories, as long as one splits into enough categories. Cochran (1968) and a follow-up Becher (1992) both recommend splitting into at least 5 categories in order to minimize the amount of residual confounding. In general. more categories is better, but you can risk over-fitting and having imprecise estimates with too few individuals in each category.

---

Becher, H. (1992). The concept of residual confounding in regression models and some applications. *Statistics in Medicine*, 11(13), 1747–1758. https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.4780111308

Cochran, W. G. (1968). The effectiveness of adjustment by subclassification in removing bias in observational studies. *Biometrics*, 295-313.